# Unable to make spaCy work in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, spacy

Can anyone maybe help me out? I am trying to run spaCy in jupyter notebook but i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-07acae5d948b> in <module>
----> 1 import spaCy
      2 
      3 # This loads a small English model trained on web data.
      4 # For other models and languages check: https://spacy.io/models
      5 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spaCy'
```

However, I have downloaded spaCy through the Mac terminal via pip3 install spacy. When I run this command again in the terminal, it says this command is already satisfied. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You should import `spacy`, all lower case.

Comment: This does not work :(

Comment: You get the same error? Can you try running `!pip install spacy` in your notebook?